# Error data not saving using Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

Hi all I am trying to save data using core data from a text field and then hit a save button.

it wasn't saving at first but now when I saveI get an error that says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a fetch request with sort descriptors'

I hope you guys can help.

```
var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<TextInputs>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    controller.delegate = self
```

and functions

```
  func attemptFetch() {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TextInputs> = TextInputs.fetchRequest()

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: DataController().managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    self.controller = controller

    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {  
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

and action

```
@IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: Any) {

    attemptFetch()

    let textInputs = TextInputs(context: DataController().managedObjectContext)

    if let page22Text = TextInputBox.text {
        textInputs.page22 = page22Text

        do {
            try DataController().managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: What happens if you add a sort descriptor to your fetch request?

Comment: Hi, I don't have a sort descriptor, I am new to Swift and programming only about 7 months experience, Sorry. I followed examples and from my tutorial and they didn't add a descriptor in.

Comment: Do you just need to fetch the `NSManagedObjects`? I don't see anywhere you're actually using your `NSFetchedResultsController`, am I wrong? If you're not using it and don't need to sort your results you don't have to have it to do a fetch in CoreData

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: *...requires a fetch request with sort descriptors*. If you are new to Swift create a new project with Core Data checkbox checked and read how Apple creates the `NSFetchedResultsController` instance. You will also run into problems if you are always creating new independent instances of `DataController()`.

Comment: Hi Pierce, I have changed my code function I had a different one copied now i have selected the correct one, i was trying the two ways in the tutorials. ut i get the same error